# Can i make a server database just like AppServ in windows Forms App?

Tags: c#, database, webserver, appserver

I'm trying to make a server database in my application so that the files in server can be access by clients.

To more clearly what i mean, i just like to trying to make application just like AppServ in Visual Studio 2008. How can i do that?

Comment: Perhaps look into sql compact, need more information to give a better ansser